# Change encoding of multiples files at same time

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

###### Problem

After updating R to 4.3.2 version, I started to face encoding issues, especially with Quarto type documents. These problems didn't occur before the update.

For some reason that I don't know what is, it seems that these type of files aren't rendering anymore with encoding other than `UTF-8` (at least in my machine after the update). The problem is that almost all my files are encoded in `ISO-8859-1`. So I'm stuck in a situation where even though I can correctly read a file in the source editor, it can't correctly render a markdown-based Quarto document.

###### What I've leanerd from this journey

I tried to change RStudio default encoding to `UTF-8` but it messes up all my files in `ISO-8859-1` - for example altering words like '**famílias**' to '**fam?lias**'. Then I noted that, to change one specific file from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`, I actually needed to take it and 'Save with encoding' in UTF-8 and then change the default RStudio encoding to `UTF-8`.

###### Question

Given this problem, and given that from what I've read *it seems like it's not good coding practice to keep files encoded in* `ISO-8859-1`, I feel inclined to change them. So my question is: **how can I transfer all my files that are encoded in `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8` without necessarily doing it one by one manually?** I apologize in advance for any misconception done!

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    

time zone: America/Sao_Paulo
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2    tools_4.3.2       rstudioapi_0.15.0 Rcpp_1.0.12       stringi_1.8.3    
[6] zip_2.3.0         openxlsx_4.2.5.2
```